# Intersection - Difference - Union of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

1) $A \setminus B =  A \cap \overline B$

2) $(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)=(A \setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$

3) $A\cup B=(A \setminus B)\cup (B \setminus A)\cup (A\cap B)$

I need to prove the following equalities of sets. I only have an idea for the first and did the following.

1) My Answer : By definition $A \setminus B = \{x \in U \mid x \in A \text{ and } x\notin B\}$.

For set B  we have the following :
$$x \in U\text{ and }\space x\in B$$
but,
$$\overline B=\{x\in U\mid x\notin B\}$$

Hence from the following facts I got,

$$A\cap \overline B=\{x\in U\mid x\in A \text{ and }\notin B.$$

I assume that this is logically true but I'm not sure whether it is true as a proof.

I'll be waiting for your comments about "1"(to my solution) and also help for "2 and 3"

Comment: You should use the logical symbols $\vee$, $\wedge$ and $\neg$. Then you can use the definition and some theorems to prove the equations. Check that first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual thing to do in this kind of proof is to show that each set (on each side of the equation) is contained in the other.

As for example in 1) you need to verify that $A\setminus B\subseteq A\cap \overline{B}$ and $A\cap \overline{B}\subseteq A\setminus B$. And this you can do taking an $x$ in $A\setminus B$ and proving that $x\in A\cap \overline{B}$ and vice-versa. But the idea to prove this is pretty similar to what you've done.

That being said, the statement 2) is false, maybe you got it written wrong because if you change the second part for $(A\setminus B)\cap(B\setminus A)$ it works.

Comment: Second part changed and thank you for the warning.  I might have lost in 2 and 3 since they are bit more long can't figure out the notation.

Can you give me starting point ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still wrong since $B\setminus B$ is the empty set

Comment: you might want to say  $B\setminus A$

Comment: And for the longer expressions just notice you can simplify them as if $C=A\cup B$ and $D=A\cap B$ then  $(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$ is equal to the easier expression $C\setminus D$ and you already know that if $x\in C\setminus D$ this means that $x\in C$ and $x\notin D$. Now, what does $x\in C$ means?

Comment: Well I assume that $$ x \in(A\cup B)$$. So this means x is either element of A or B ?

Comment: not that is just $x$ being in $C$ but you want it to don't be in $D$ as well. Also, you will never get a proof for 2) as you have it written because it is NOT true.

Comment: I corrected it now.